# How to mockup an entityManager for unit testing a service

Tags: dependency-injection, mocking, mockito, junit4, hibernate-entitymanager

I´m trying to write some unit tests for my company, so its not possible for me to change anything in sourceCode but everything in the tests.
I´m using Java8, Spring, Mockito and JUnit4.

Problem: There are some services with a entityManager, which gets instantiated via dependencyInjection

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = someName)
private EntityManager em;
```

I tried to mock this and injecting it into my ClassUnderTest, like i mocked every other class but that doesn´t work.

```
@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private SomeService testedSomeService;
```

There´s always an "IllegalStateException: Failed to load application context" before running the first test, with a hint to the entity manager. 
If i make the annotation to a comment, every method gets tested fine (except the methods, using entityManager).

Is there a simple way to mock the entityManager? or how can i inject a dependency in my testclass?

I appreciate ANY help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {

    @Mock
    private EntityManager em;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.reset(em);
    }

    //your junits

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You use @Mock, that's all. @InjectMocks is for the service which uses EntityManager, not for EntityManager. And @Autowired is for real instanciation and injection via context, which only exists in an integrated test, not in an unit test, as what you do here.
Just use @Mock.